# Tags that format the indented code: what precedence is given?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, code-formatting

Here is an example:

[VBA openweathermap XML retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410442/vba-openweathermap-xml-retrieval/24415509#24415509)

The code used in this Q is VBA. OP has also tagged it as XML (which I would consider appropriate since it's dealing with XML parsing, programmatically).

However, the XML tag seems to take precedence over other tags for formatting the indented code in the question.  I have seen this a few other times.

I tried to edit the tags, so that vba or excel-vba would appear *before* xml, in the list of tags, thus properly formatting it for VBA. But any time I add an xml tag, that tag immediately goes to the front of the line, and changes the way the rendered code is formatted.

It appears this precedence given by the # of followers/questions. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are ordered by the number of questions.

If you need to force syntax highlighting for a particular language, you can do that with a comment directive placed before the code block you want to highlight. In this case: `<!-- language: lang-vb -->`.

For more information, see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Linked question (and everything I've seen before) says "If there's more than one tag that has syntax highlighting, it uses a default and lets Prettify infer what's the best language to use.". Is this (ordering on question count) a recent change?

Comment: The tags are ordered by number of questions, this doesn't come into play with the syntax highlight, AFAIK, @Billy